# Reverse for 'idnome' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['viewInscricao/(?P<pk_test>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, view

In my views I do this:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.user.participant:
        current_user = request.user
        subscriptionUser = int(Subscription.objects.get(participant=current_user.participant).id)
        
    else:
            pass

    return render(request,
                template_name='inscricao/index.html',
                context={'getID':subscriptionUser}
                )
```

And in my html I do this:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'idnome' getID %}">
                        Consultar A Minha Inscrição
                </a>
```

I have tried so many different ways, but I have no result. If I put a number instead of `getID` in the html, it works. If I let `getID` I get this:

> Reverse for `'idnome'` with arguments `'('',)'` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['viewInscricao/(?P<pk_test>[0-9]+)/$']`

Comment: And if you use `subscription.pk` in your html instead of `getID`?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've not included you URL patterns, I'll assume the path which django tried to use is the URL you want to link to;

`'viewInscricao/(?P<pk_test>[0-9]+)/$'`

This has a kwarg of `pk_test` so what you need to do to link to it is;

`<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'idnome' pk_test=getID %}">Link</a>`

I would make a few changes, to do something like this, which also fixes a bug if the user doesn't have a participant;

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.participant:
        current_user = request.user
        subscription_user = Subscription.objects.get(
            participant=current_user.participant
        )
        context.update({'subscription_id': subscription_user.id})
    else:
        pass

    return render(
        request,
        template_name='inscricao/index.html',
        context=context
    )
```

```
{% if subscription_id %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'idnome' pk_test=subscription_id %}">
        Consultar A Minha Inscrição
    </a>
{% endif %}
```